# How to display a calculated field alongside the original table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Stock, it contains a variety of fields of which two of them are price and quantity. How do I display all of the contents of the original table as well as the calculated field(quantity * price).

I tried

```
SELECT (Quantity * Price) FROM Stock;
```

This displayed the calculated field, but I am having trouble displaying this calculated field alongside the original table.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT *, Quantity * Price FROM Stock;
```

This will print first all the fields of the Stock table and then your calculated field

Comment: Also, it might be neater to use aliases, so try `SELECT *, Quantity*Price AS Calculation FROM Stock;`. At the end of your table you will have `Calculation` column.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to accomplish. If you want every value you can just use the `*`-wildcard in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *, (Quantity * Price) AS Calculation FROM Stock;
```

This will result in something like this:

```
ID  |  Name   |  Quantity  |  Price  |  Calculation
----+---------+------------+---------+---------------
 0  | Banana  | 100        | 10      | 1000
 1  | Apple   | 15         | 10      | 150
 2  | Orange  | 20         | 5       | 100
 3  | Pizza   | 3          | 15      | 45
```

As you can see, using the `AS`-keyword, you have created an alias for the calculation and the result will be accessible by this alias.